# can a .htaccess file malfunction

Tags: apache, .htaccess, security

In some CMS backup system i see they use the following .htaccess code in the backup folder:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from none
```

I was wondering if this is fail safe or if it is possible to annoy the server so badly that the .htaccess file is being ignored.

The reason I ask this is because if that is possible I would rather put the files outside the httpdocs folder so they are not accessible by a browser. That though requires me to use quite some extra's to show or use those files if i want to.

Anyone have an idea or tips?

Comment: Are your backup files still accessible through http ?

Comment: Well a normal http request to the files would fail due to the htaccess file in the backup folder. But I am wondering if it is possible to annoy the server or do something to take away the functionality of the htaccess file, so that the backup files indeed become accessible

Comment: No, there's no way to bypass this feature.